# Numpy.arange(start, end, step) equivalent in Java for float values

Tags: java, python, numpy

Do you know the way to achieve `numpy.arange(start, end, step)` functionality in Java for float values? I know there is a `numpy.arange(start, end, 1)` equivalent for `int` values in Java 8, ie. `static IntStream range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`. I also know custom implementation of Python `range(start, end, step)` function, but also only for Integers (["Pythonish integer range in Java"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112461/pythonish-integer-range-in-java)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, (int)((end-start)/step))
    .mapToDouble(x -> x*step + start)
```

Comment: Now it seems so obvious... Thank you very much.

Comment: don't forget the .toArray() at the end to convert it from DoubleStream to array